# can't connect to MySQL with GCP VM Instance docker ERROR 2002 (HY000)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I have a VM instance booting on `container optimised OS` and with the following Startup script:

```
docker pull gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.16

docker run -d \
  -p 0.0.0.0:3306:3306 \
  gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.16 /cloud_sql_proxy \
  -instances=<cloudsql-connection-name>=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306
```

When trying to connect to the db running the following command from the cloud shell `mysql -ppass -u root` I have the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

What does this mean? What should I do?

The context is that I need to use this vm mysql proxy to connect data fusion.

Answer (score 3):

Add this command line option to connect via TCP:

```
-h 127.0.0.1
```

Example:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -ppass -u root
```

Note: You are specifying an older version of the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy container.

https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/cloudsql-docker/GLOBAL/gce-proxy

Comment: tried it and got the following error ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Comment: @SimonBreton - Launch the container without the `-d` flag and check for output that indicates an error. Double-check that your user identity has a Cloud SQL role permitting access. Also upgrade the container to the `latest` version. `gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:latest`.